# Why in different themes different buttons are created?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-button, material-components-android

I have an usual button and a theme which is applied to `android:theme` in `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/supperButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp" />
```

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>
```

When i inflate this button and stop the app with debugger to see what class has been created i see the following:
[image]

As you can see, instead of an usual button class, `AppComapatButton` has been created. When i change theme to as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

`MaterialButton` is created, instead of an usual button class or `AppComapatButton`:

[image]

**Question:** as i can gather, themes can define what exactly type of a widget is used. So what exactly does define it? Maybe there is some attribute in a theme that does it ?

Comment: Yeah, you've got it mostly figured out. Appcompat introduced a mechanism by which a specialized `LayoutInflater` helper class can be specified with the `viewInflaterClass` theme attribute. The base class [`AppCompatViewInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatViewInflater) substitutes the AppCompat versions of certain widgets, and Material Components simply sets its own class to sub its versions. Note that the subs are done only for tags that are not fully qualified class names; i.e., `<Button>` will be subbed, but `<android.widget.Button>` will not.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if your `Activity` extends `AppCompatActivity`.

The `AppCompatActivity` calls the `setFactory2` method using a custom implementation of LayoutInflater.
This implementation is done by the [**`AppCompatViewInflater`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatViewInflater)
which checks the names of the views in the layout and automatically "substitutes" all usages of core Android widgets inflated from layout files by the AppCompat extensions of those widgets.

You can check in the source code:

```
@Nullable
public final View createView(/**...*/) {
    //...
    switch (name) {
        case "Button":
            view = createButton(context, attrs);
            verifyNotNull(view, name);
            break;
     //...
}

@NonNull
protected AppCompatButton createButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return new AppCompatButton(context, attrs);
}
```

In the MaterialComponents theme is defined another implemetantion, the [**`MaterialComponentsViewInflater`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java).

For example you can check in the source code:

```
@Override
  protected AppCompatButton createButton(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull AttributeSet attrs) {
    return new MaterialButton(context, attrs);
  }
```

You can use an own inflater adding in the app theme the **`viewInflaterClass`** attribute:

```
  <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    <item name="viewInflaterClass">com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater</item>
  </style>
```